# React.js: Sortable component

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, reactjs

I used a SmartSortable snippet by Pete Hunt from [React.js Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/reactjs/mHfBGI3Qwz4/_vnwOellnyoJ) that intergates jQuery UI sortable with React.

Unfortunately, after using it, editing input fields makes the text cursor to just to the end of the currently edited input field.

[image: Animated GIF]

http://jsfiddle.net/NV/jfkn5/

Removing `<SmartSortable>` from the example fixes the problem.

Why is it happening? I believe, the `<input>`’s value get’s updated despite being exactly the same; I don’t understand why.

Comment: It's happening because on each update the code clones the child and re-renders it. While maybe not kosher, you can let it edit the children instead of clone it by removing the call to `cloneWithProps` in `SmartSortable.componentDidUpdate`: http://jsfiddle.net/ssorallen/jfkn5/2/